# How to replace string with consecutive instances?

Tags: c#, regex, replace

**EDIT**

@Ulugbek - I've edited to question to clarify.

I'm using a pattern as a delimiter and need to replace consecutive pattern occurrences by inserting a $ between the patterns using C#, but currently it only replaces the first instance of the pattern.

Is there something else I need to do other than run it through the replace several times? Or, do I need to use RegEx?

Thanks

```
String s = "ABCThis is a delimited valueABCABCABCAnd another delimited valueABC";
String.Replace("ABCABC", "ABC$ABC"); //misses second instance of the consecutive patterns instances
```

Results:

> ABCThis is a delimited valueABC$ABCABCAnd another delimited valueABC

Desired Results:

> ABCThis is a delimited valueABC$ABC$ABCAnd another delimited valueABC

Ulugbek Solution:

> ABC$This is a delimited valueABC$ABC$ABC$And another delimited
>   valueABC$

Thanks

Comment: call Replace in a loop until the result does not change anymore?

Comment: If you count the instances of your pattern and the result is 2, then why is the desired result not `ABC$ABCABC$ABC` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can rethink the strategy. Replace all `ABC`s followed by `ABC` with `ABC$`.

```
string s = "ABCABCABC";
string output = Regex.Replace(s, "ABC(?=ABC)", "ABC$");
```

Comment: @user2732180 Can you provide more details why it wouldn't work?

Comment: @user2732180 Hardly can see how does my code generate: `ABC$This is a delimited valueABC$ABC$ABC$And another delimited valueABC$`? Did you try to execute it?

Comment: Following the same idea: `Regex.Replace(s, "(?<=ABC)(?=ABC)", "$");`

Comment: @PauloMorgado Yes, it makes sense. But somehow even regex without lookbehind doesn't work for OP.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov - Forgive me! It's late and I glanced at your solution without trying it believing it wouldn't work. It does in fact work as you suggested.

Comment: @PauloMorgado - Your solution works as well. However, after trying both solutions on the source file, the average execution time was 23.5s whereas Ulugbek's solution averaged 21s. Therefore, I'm giving  him the points. Thank you very much for your help though.